# How to hide generated folders in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on an android project but I see some of the auto-generated code from my file tree as you can see in the picture

How can I hide them (the ones with green color)

[image]

Comment: You might be happier switching to the Project view via the selector above the tree. Right now, it looks like you are on the Android view.

Answer (score 2):

**To hide generated folders in Android Studio:**

Go to **"File" > "Settings"**.
Navigate to **"Editor" > "File Types"**.
Scroll down to **"Ignore files and folders"**.
Add the folders you want to hide, such as **"build", "gen",** and **"out"**.
Click **"Apply"** and **"OK".**

Answer (score 1):

If you are not happy with switching the project view,

You can right click on the directory that you need to hide and select,

`Mark Directory as -> excluded`

if you want to include a directory back, find the path of your excluded directory and,

`right click -> Mark Directory as -> Cancel Exclusion`